# submonand leak (blaze-html empty output with forM_ )

Tags: haskell, monads, ghc

I am writing a web app with blaze-html library.
Static content is generated without issues, but I stuck with generating dynamic content.

```
-- compiles, runs but expanded into empty string
forM_ [1,2,3] (\x -> return $ (H.p . H.toHtml . show) x)
```

```
-- while this is working as expect ed
forM_ [1,2,3] n $ (H.p . H.toHtml . show) x)
```

Looks like this time bug sneaks Haskell type checker.

My investigation

```
:t forM_
forM_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t a -> (a -> m b) -> m ()

:t   (H.p . H.toHtml . show) 
(H.p . H.toHtml . show) :: Show a => a -> H.Html


:t  (\x -> return $ (H.p . H.toHtml . show)  x)
(\x -> return $ (H.p . H.toHtml . show)  x)
  :: (Monad m, Show a) => a -> m H.Html

type H.Html = H.Markup
type H.Markup = H.MarkupM ()
instance Monand H.MarkupM
```

So in the correct case "m b" = "MarkupM ()" and markup preserved when returning from the loop.
In error case "m b" = "m (MarkupM ())" and m is some type constructor constrained with Monad class.
So H.toHtml creates new MarkupM which is filled by H.p and after that sub MarkukM is discarded, right?

How to deal with such kind of bug?

Here it is the app:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

module Lib
    ( startApp
    , app
    ) where


import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.TH
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Servant
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Servant.HTML.Blaze
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5.Attributes as A

type API = Get '[HTML] H.Html

api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy


endpoint :: Handler H.Html
endpoint = do
  return $ H.docTypeHtml $ do
    H.head $ do
      H.title "title"
    H.body $ do
      H.h1 "header"
      forM_ [1,2,3] (\x -> return $ (H.p . H.toHtml . show) x)

app :: Application
app = serve api (hoistServer api id endpoint)

startApp :: IO ()
startApp = runSettings defaultSettings app
```

Comment: Why do you have `return` in one of them and not in the other? (Hint: that's your problem).

Comment: I put return just in case was hoping that type checker will point the problem anyway.

Comment: I don't understand the snippet that's "working as expected". What is `n` there? What is `x`?

Comment: @RobinZigmond and of course there is the case of the missing `(`

Comment: `forM_` executes side effects and discards the result. `return` has no side effects.